# Express app failing to connect without errors

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I have been trying to connect my express app, but for some reason it is just not connecting.

I am going to "IP:PORT" on chrome and I get a typical "Refused to connect" error.

I am using node.js, and the latest version of express.

"Received" does not print to the console, however it logs "App listening on port 8088"

I have tried a lot of things, hosting on digital ocean, no connection. I am currently trying it in VSC (Ip address is my ipv4 address)

When trying using HTTP, I get a connect fail error.

My code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

const fs = require('fs');

require('dotenv').config()

const serverKey = process.env.SERVER_KEY
const port = process.env.PORT




function randomString(length, chars) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
  return result;
}




module.exports = {
  async execute(client) {
    console.log('Test')
    app.post("/getVerificationCode", function (req, res, next) {
      console.log("Recieved")
      if (req.body.serverKey !== serverKey) {
        console.log("Invalid serverKey supplied.")

        return res.status(403).json({
          error: "You do not have permission to use this."
        })
      }

      let verificationCode = randomString(4, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ').toUpperCase()
      const userID = parseInt(req.body.userid)
      console.log(verificationCode)

      client.verificationCodes[userID] = {
        code: verificationCode
      }

      fs.writeFile("./codes.json", JSON.stringify(client.verificationCodes, null, 4), err => {
        if (err) throw err
      })

      return res.status(200).json({
        VerificationCode: verificationCode
      })
    })

    app.get("/*", function (req, res, next) {
      return res.status(200).json({})
    })

    app.listen(port)
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)

  }
}
```

"Test" does log, so the module **IS** being required. Before, I was trying it in my server.js, but that did not work and the code was messy, so I moved it into a folder.

I would really appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: What is the value of client in execute function? Can you know me?

Comment: I guess the reason is that receive is not print that, you use get method and you have described here post HTTP method for an API. Can you please verify? I guess this might be the reason.

Comment: @Dipak Interestingly, when I put it on glitch (the project), it works.

Comment: Why starting the http server everytime `execute` gets called? You also register/override for every `execute` call a http handler. Your code is salad and should be refactored.